# How can I best search for directories that contain a specific subdirectory OR a specific file?

Tags: bash, search, grep, find

I need to perform a search on a vast directory structure and output the top level directories that do not contain either a specific subdirectory (in this case "master") OR those that contain any .wav files.

Ex

```
    001\Master\files.wav
    002\files.wav
    003\Admin\otherfiles.txt
```

In this case, I need only the directory 003 to be printed to a file.

The string I have started is as follows:

```
find . d -depth 2 \! -exec test -e '{}master' \; > folders.txt
```

This got me at least headed in the right direction.

I also tried & running two concurrent find requests and grep to get the output but that has not worked so far. I also tried to find a way to 'grep -v' but I could not.  Anyone have any thoughts?

I have even thought about writing a script to handle the search, doing the initial find, then performing a second search on the output to give me only those directories I need.

Comment: are you sure, the find command exports the file list with `\' not `/`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this, but locically I would do something like this

```
find . -name "*.wav" $(printf "! -name %s " master)
```

you can replace string master with whatever you want to exclude

Since in your question you mentioned you only need level1 folder you can use AWK command

```
find .  -name "*.wav" $(printf "! -name %s " master) | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . |egrep -i -v "\\\\master\\\\|wav$" | awk -F '/' '{print $2}' |sort -u
```

or

```
find . |egrep -i -v "\\\\master\\\\|wav$" | awk -F '/' '{a[$2]++}END{for (i in a) print i , a[i]}' |sort -u
```

Comment: I just tried this string, but it returns the error `egrep: infile: no such file or directory`

Comment: You may want to add more explanation regarding how/why this works. As it is, this does not really answer the question.

Comment: The above string prints every parent directory 7-12 times regardless of contents.

Comment: Thanks for your help BMW - however now the first string simply prints the top level directories, and the second adds a number next to the directories which I have yet been able to decipher. I assume it has something to do with 'a[i]' but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
for topdir in */
do [ "`find $topdir \( -name Master -o -name \*.wav \) -print -quit`" ] || echo $topdir
done
```

If your `find` doesn't know `-quit` and complains of `` invalid predicate `-quit' ``, just remove the `-quit` (the command may take longer then).